# Change cursor position after inserting text in div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have some trouble with inserting new text in `div` tag (id=mainDiv). I want to when insert text in current caret position it added and then move cursor to new position (old position + text.length). But I see wrong logic. Help me please!

```js
function getCharacterOffsetWithin(range, node) 
{
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        node,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        function(node) {
            var nodeRange = document.createRange();
            nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
            return nodeRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, range) < 1 ?
                NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        },
        false
    );

    var charCount = 0;
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        charCount += treeWalker.currentNode.length;
    }
    if (range.startContainer.nodeType == 3) {
        charCount += range.startOffset;
    }
    return charCount;
}

function input(text)
{
    //FIX LOGIC!
    
    var target;
    if(window.getSelection)
    {
        target =window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        target = ((target.nodeType===1)?target:target.parentNode);
    }
    else if(document.selection) {
        target = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newpos = getCharacterOffsetWithin(range, target) + text.length;
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
    
    target.focus();
    var newRange = document.createRange(); 
    newRange.setStart(target, newpos);
    newRange.setEnd(target, newpos);
    newRange.collapse(false);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(newRange);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="formulas.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body id="main" spellcheck="false"> 
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <button onclick="input('Ln')">Ln</button>
            <button onclick="input('Lg')">Lg</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#177;');">+-</button>
            <button onclick="input('x&#178;')">x&#178;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#945;')">&#945;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#946;')">&#946;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#947;')">&#947;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#931;')">&#931;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#247;')">&#247;</button>
            <button onclick="input('&#215;')">&#215;</button>
        </span> 
        </p>
        <div id = "mainDiv"contenteditable="true" onclick="mainClick(event)">dwawdawdd</div>  
        <div class="big" onclick="setCursorPositionToEnd();"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
range.insertNode(textNode);

target.focus();
var newRange = document.createRange(); 
newRange.setStart(textNode, text.length);
```

i just set start position for new node.